# Azure DevOps Rest API - How to grab assigned user's display name in work item

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, workitem

I want to get the display name of the assigned user on an Azure DevOps work item.

```
// Get client
VssConnection connection = GetVssConnection(_azureDevopsOptions);
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

// Define fields
string startDateField = "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate";
string finishDateField = "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate";
string assignedToField = "System.AssignedTo";

// Get work item
var workitemTask = await workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemAsync(taskId);

// Get fields from work item
var startDate = workitemTask.Fields.ContainsKey(startDateField) ? workitemTask.Fields[startDateField] : 0;
var finishDate = workitemTask.Fields.ContainsKey(finishDateField) ? workitemTask.Fields[finishDateField] : 0;
var assignedTo = workitemTask.Fields.ContainsKey(assignedToField) ? workitemTask.Fields[assignedToField] : 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you should parse the value of `assignedToField` into a `JObject`:

`JObject identity = JObject.FromObject(workitemTask.Fields[assignedToField]);`

Then the display name is available as `identity["DisplayName"]`.